# Android Signed APKS flavor signed with same keystore

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-productflavors

I am working on 37 flavors of a single applications with different keystores.
I want to generate an update APK of all these flavors together, in doing so the Android Studio gives the option of selecting multiple flavors while generating signed apk.

If I select multiple flavors the Android Studio is signing all those flavors with the same keystore but not with the keystore information that i have mentioned for each flavors in build.gradle signingConfigs block.

I think the correct behavior should be to generate all flavors APK using the signingConfigs block information not the one which was entered in the Generate Signed APK wizard.

Comment: `./gradlew assembleRelease`??

Comment: When I run that command on command line I get sun.tools.attach.WindowsAttachProvider could not be instantiated, it runs fine through studio why does this command gives NewRelic API no Providers Attached error.

Comment: Just try to perform for specific flavour first, let's say flavor A. `./gradlew assembleARelease`. See whether the same happens.

Comment: Ok, let me try it now and see what happens.

Comment: The command must run on project root folder right? so what would we do to run it for specific flavor?

Comment: Just run from terminal `./gradlew assembleMacdonaldsRelease` where `Macdonalds` is your flavor name. You can check the actual command name in the Gradle tasks list at the right side of the Android Studio.

Comment: Tried running this command for a single flavor gives the same error, com.sun.tools.attach.spi.AttachProvider: Pr
[newrelic] Error encountered while loading the New Relic agent